# Type hint where one argument is the type of another

Tags: python, generics, type-hinting

I'm having trouble expressing the precise type hints for a pair of parameters where one needs to be a value that is an instance of some type, and the other needs to be the type itself, or some super-type.

One case where you see this in Python is in the `__exit__` method for a context manager (class).

```py
import typing as t
from types import TracebackType
from contextlib import AbstractContextManager

class Acme(AbstractContextManager):
  def __exit__(self, exc_type: t.Type[Exception], exc: Exception,
      tb: Tracebacktype) -> None:
    ...
```

This specific case may not matter, because context managers are handled internally by Python, but I'd still like to understand how to express two arguments where the first one is the (super-)type of the second one.

Conceptually, my problem is I want to express that the value `exc` has the type `exc_type` or some subtype. In the expression above, I guess mypy would be perfectly happy with arguments like `LookupError, RuntimeError('foo')` even though a `RuntimeError` isn't a type of `LookupError`. Is there a better way to express this where mypy would catch that kind of mistake?

**Update**

Trying a test case here using TypeVars:

```py
import typing as t

C = t.TypeVar('C', bound=t.Collection)

def f(t: t.Type[C], c: C) -> None:
  pass

f(t.Dict, [])
```

I'd expect mypy to complain about this code, because even though the empty list is a type of Collection, it's not a dictionary.

Comment: I tried for a while, but the [PEP](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/8352) generally seems to discourage and several [issues](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/8352) support this. This would be useful feature but it would require `Type[some_type_var]` to do a lot more. Philosophically, `TypeVar` is the way to go.

Comment: @modesitt If that's how it is, then that's how it is. I'd accept an answer of "it's not possible to do this" with supporting evidence, if it were an answer and not a comment.

Comment: I think the correct answer to this question will change within a year or two. Let's revisit in 2021.

Comment: Yes, I hope so! Python's typing is improving by leaps and bounds. That said, I would almost rather see mypy support inferred typing of abstract methods (like `__exit__`) so that instead of worrying about a precise annotation, it's done for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This kind of use of `Type[some_type_var]` is seemingly discouraged by a seciton in the [PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#the-type-of-class-objects) where only a subset of this support is provided (notably for binding `TypeVar`s to class types). It appears this discouragement is not phillisophical (this would be a common use of generics in a language where types and values are both first-class) - but more related to the practical implementation of type checkers. The use of `TypeVar` for classmethod signatures - a special case of your question - was even a [late addition to the pep](https://github.com/python/peps/commit/ada7d3566e26edf5381d1339b61e48a82c51c566).

---

Possible solutions that *do not work with mypy (as of now)*:

#### Standard `TypeVar`

There is no type checking in function signatures of `Type[some_type_var]`. This is not variable based on if `some_type_var` is [`contravariant` or `covariant`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypeVar) (nor should it be).

#### `TypeVar` of `Type[TypeVar]`

```
T = TypeVar("T")
Meta = TypeVar("Meta", bound=Type[T])

def foo(the_type: Meta, the_value: T):
   ....
```

`T` and `Meta` can not "bind" together .

---

To my surprise, in some cases you can squeeze out a bit of this behavior (but this is a special case and this seems undefined to me)

```
T = TypeVar('T', str, int, float, bytes)

class Foo:

    def bar(self, the_type: Type[T], the_value: T):
        print(isinstance(the_value, the_type))

f = Foo()
f.bar(str, "baz")
f.bar(str, b"baz")  # wrong!
f.bar(int, 1)
f.bar(int, 3.15159)  # wrong! (but no complaint)
f.bar(float, 1.0)
f.bar(float, 1)  # wrong! (but no complaint)
f.bar(float, b'1.0')  # wrong!
```

Giving

```
so.py:nn: error: Value of type variable "T" of "bar" of "Foo" cannot be "object"
so.py:nn: error: Value of type variable "T" of "bar" of "Foo" cannot be "object"
Found 2 errors in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

But only seemingly for python's primitive types (this will not work with user-space types) (and again, only *some* of  python's primitive types as shown (see the *error-miss* with `float` and `int`). I think this is a clear "nice-to-have" extension of `TypeVar` (and makes more `Generic` use-cases possible).

---

There are some related issues on mypy about this:

1. [about class annotation behavior](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/8352)
2. [`TypeVar` of a `TypeVar`](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/6541)

Answer (score 0):

This is what `TypeVar`s are for!  You want something like:

```
from types import TracebackType
from typing import Type, TypeVar
from contextlib import AbstractContextManager

_E = TypeVar('_E', bound=Exception)

class Acme(AbstractContextManager):
    def __exit__(
        self,
        exc_type: Type[_E],
        exc: _E,
        tb: Tracebacktype
    ) -> None:
    ...
```

Comment: Hmm, I tried that, but mypy is perfectly happy with my obviously wrong test case (where I pass in LookupError as the type of a ZeroDivisionError). I'll update my question with what I've tried.